# ComponentDidUpdate() keeps calling the API always even after having condition

Tags: reactjs

So I have a component which will be called in parent component when a button clicked. I have added a condition to run `ComponentDidUpdate` run only once. But still it calls the API multiple times. Here is my code:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  var seqNum = this.props.seqNum;

  // Condition to control multiple requests
  if (prevProps.seqNum !== seqNum) {
   this.getCheckList();
  }
}

getCheckList() {
  var seqNum = this.props.seqNum;
  var vehicleId = this.props.vehicleId;

  // Get EventDetails
  var urlLink = "getEvent?vehicleId=" + vehicleId + "&seqNum=" + seqNum;
  axios.get(urlLink)
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({ eventData: res.data })
      console.log(res.data + "This fil")
  })
}
```

Why is this happening ? Any ideas? Or if you need any additional info, just ask me. I will update the code here.

Comment: What happens if you `console.log()` `prevProps.seqNum` and `seqNum` before that if statement?

Comment: @James it returns the current seqnum an, undenied for prevprops on first click

Comment: getCheckList = () => {..function} , try like this

Comment: The problem with `ComonentDidUpdate` function. It calls exactly 4 times . sometimes , it runs infinite times

Comment: where does `seqNum` is modified, at what stage. it needed to be different for the condition to return false.

Comment: I'm using this component in another parent component. Whenever a button clicks from that component, this child component will render with props

Answer (score 1):

in you state initializing in your component constructor set eventData: null

then try this :

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  var seqNum = this.props.seqNum;
  var eventData= this.state.eventData;
  //Condition to control multiple requests

  // or you can add something to check state for fetching more than once !
  if(prevProps.seqNum !== seqNum && (!eventData || prevState.eventData != eventData ) {
   this.getCheckList();
  }
}

getCheckList() {
 var seqNum = this.props.seqNum;
 var vehicleId = this.props.vehicleId;
 //Get EventDetails
 var urlLink = "getEvent?vehicleId="+vehicleId+"&seqNum="+seqNum;
 axios.get(urlLink)
   .then(res => {
     this.setState({eventData: res.data})
     console.log(res.data+ "This fil")
   })
}
```

or maybe just this enough :

```
if(prevProps.seqNum !== seqNum && !eventData  )
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time . But still I it calls the function multiple times . :(

Comment: This condition : if(prevProps.seqNum !== seqNum && !eventData  ) never let to call again if your fetch have a data : this.setState({eventData: res.data}) maybe return value is null !

Comment: I don't know what's wrong here .. But still it keeps running multiple times.

Comment: I rectified the problem that , I actually calling the Child component always in parent component. I have to find a solution to control it